# Как сделать привязку данных внутри пользовательского элемента управления?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть наследник от UserControl. Есть у него несколько DependencyProperty. Например Property1 и Property2.

Как в xaml сделать привязку Property1 к Property2?

```
<UserControl x:Class="ViewerControls.SchemaArrow"
    Property1 = "{Binding Path=Property2}"/>
```

не пашет, потому что там, где я указал Property1 можно указывать только свойства, наследуемые от UserControl, а на новые компилятор ругается.

Comment: Покажите больше кода. Это _объявление_ контрола или его _использование_? Это важно.

Comment: @VladD, я знаю, что это важно. Но там видно же, что это объявление. Не могу дать больше кода, там его совсем много :). Скажите, что конкретно нужно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю, правильно ли я понял проблему. Когда мы использовали не `UserControl`, а `CustomControl`, то можно было сделать такое дополнение свойствами. Прошу прощения, если отвечаю не по теме...

В данном примере UserControl расширяется до моего `BusyContentControl`. Как бы контрол-контейнер, который в случае, когда его свойство `IsBusy` устанавливается в true, то появляется Busy Indicator (бегущий червячок, что загрузка) ну и соответственно отображается Busy Status - сообщение пользователю над бегущим червячком. Если сопоставлять с названиями в Вашем вопросе, то вместо `SchemaArrow` - `MyUserControl`. Вместо `Property1` и `Property2` - `IsBusy` и `BusyStatus`.

По [этой](http://www.vitaliy.org/Node/View/62) ссылке написано чем отличаются Custom от User контролов. Когда создается новый `CustomControl`, то XAML находится в `ResourceDictionary` (в файле generic.xaml) в папке Themes.

---

Код кастомного контрола:

```
public class BusyContentControl : ContentControl
{
    static BusyContentControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(BusyContentControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(BusyContentControl)));
    }

    public bool IsBusy
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsBusyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsBusyProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsBusyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsBusy", typeof(bool), typeof(BusyContentControl), new PropertyMetadata(false));

    public string BusyStatus
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(BusyStatusProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BusyStatusProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BusyStatusProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("BusyStatus", typeof(string), typeof(BusyContentControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));


}
```

Здесь логично, что `BusyContentControl : ContentControl`. Но в принципе, для создания `CustomControl` не обязательно наследоваться от `ContentControl`, можно так же от `FrameworkElement` или `UserControl` или `Button`...

XAML:

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SomeNamespace.Infrastructure"
xmlns:ext="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:BusyContentControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:BusyContentControl}">
                <ctrl:BusyIndicator IsBusy="{TemplateBinding IsBusy}">
                    <ctrl:BusyIndicator.BusyContent>
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding BusyStatus}" />
                    </ctrl:BusyIndicator.BusyContent>
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                            Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}"
                            >
                        <ContentPresenter
                            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                            ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}"
                            />
                    </Border>
                </ctrl:BusyIndicator>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Чтобы потом пользоваться этим кастомным контролом, надо создать новый `UserControl`, но в коде заменить, что наследуемся не от `UserControl`, а от `BusyContentControl` (а в xaml еще и префикс будет, в данном случае `infr:BusyContentControl`):

```
using SomeNamespace.Infrastructure;

public partial class MyUserControl: BusyContentControl
{
    public MyUserControl(object viewModel)
    {
        DataContext = viewModel;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

}
```

XAML:

```
<infr:BusyContentControl 
    x:Class="Module.ReportSet1.MyUserControl"
    xmlns:infr="clr-namespace:SomeNamespace.Infrastructure;assembly=MySolution.Infrastructure"
    IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy}"
    BusyStatus="{Binding BusyStatus}"/>
```

Comment: Пример хороший. Отмечу как решение, хоть сам это и не буду использовать по некоторым причинам )

Answer (score 2):

Если это у вас использование `UserControl`'а, вы должны пользоваться *настоящим* типом контрола:

```
<vc:SchemaArrow Property1="{Binding Property2, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```

Если это у вас декларация `UserControl`'а, то биндить свойства в ней — плохая идея: зачем вам тогда два свойства? Если всё же очень надо, допишите в конструкторе после `InitializeComponent()`

```
SetBinding(Property1Property, new Binding(Property2Property.Name) { Source = this });
```

Не забывайте, что Binding проводится к `DataContext`'у, а не к текущему контролу! Без указания Source `Property2` будет искаться в вашей VM.

Comment: Да, в коде я и так привязку сделал, мне просто интересно, как это сделать в xaml без лишних телодвижений. Два свойства мне нужны для двух способов декларации элемента. Есть стрелка из четырех частей, она по умолчанию чертится в направлении северо-запад по всей величине контрола горизонтально. Далее есть три свойства, которые позволяют изменять направления (например, чтобы она была вертикальная и смотрела на юго-восток). Это все хорошо, но есть случаи, когда удобнее просто задать две точки (начало и конец) и направление (горизонтально или вертикально) строкой, типа "v 0,0 100 100".

Comment: Такая строка задаст размер (100х100) и вертикальное направление (то есть треугольник - окончание стрелки будет смотреть вниз). Иначе бы мне пришлось отдельно задавать Width, Height, Orientation, ArrowDirection и Invertion. И еще, если стрелка на канве, то она отрисуется с начальными координатами (0, 0) :)

Comment: Кстати, биндинг мне не очень то и помогает. Например, задал я в свойстве строку "v 0,0 100 100". Width и Height привязались к этому свойству и изменили свое значение. После того, как я задал Width вручную, привязка слетела и дальнейшие изменения координат ширину уже не меняют.

Comment: Ну да, это by design. Width задаётся либо через привязку, либо вручную, понятно. Делайте не так: задавайте не `Width`, а `ProposedWidth` (вам ридётся добавить дополнительное свойство), и вычисляйте `Width` исходя из того, что из свойств юзер реально задал.